# Cant create CNAME Record in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, cname

I have a domain (mydomain.com).  I use AWS Route 53 to point this comain to a server hosted on EC2.
I was able to add a CNAME record for 'www.mydomain.com' or 'someprefix.mydomain.com'.
Route 53 has SOA and NS record for 'mydomain.com' and does not allow to add a CNAME record for 'mydomain.com'.

I need this record to be able to type the domain with or without the leading 'www' in the browser.

More important, I plan to run a mail server on the machine and I believe mail clients need to resolve the 'mydomain.com' part of my user email addresses (e.g. user@mydomain.com).

How do I do that?

Comment: To whoever voted this post down, could you please provide a comment why you did so?  Perhaps that could help me write better posts in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it all hang together...
Set up

- A      mydomain.com       # Sets up your main domain
- CNAME  www.mydomain.com   # Sets up your www domain.  (you may want to
                             redirect one to the other to avoid duplicate content
- NS     ns.whatever.com
        ns2.whatever.com
- MX     mail.mydomain.com

This is assuming your not using ELB

A CNAME cannot point to the root domain.  Same DNS services will allow it, but a CNAME should point to a service on the domain.  ie - the www service in the above case.